# Testing Windows Store app with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-devops, vstest

I'm trying to set up continuous integration testing for a Windows Store (8.1) app on Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online).

Setting up build was fairly easy, but I have not been able to get it to run my unit tests on a Hosted Agent. So far I have:

- Added `/t:Publish` to the build to produce the test runner `.appx`
- Created a Powershell script to install the appropriate certificates onto the agent
- Modified the test search path to find the `.appx`

Now, I'm getting errors about installing a developer license:

> Error: Could not start test run for unit tests for Windows Store app: No valid developer license found for running unit tests for Windows Store apps. Please install/renew your developer license..

It does not appear to be possible to add a developer license strictly from Powershell or Command Prompt, so is there some other way of running the tests on a Hosted Agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using vNext build and Universal Windows Platform template by following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/apps/universal).

As the developer license is deprecated in the Windows 10 operating system, Universal Windows Platform template doesn't require developer license. But if the computer that hosts the build agent will be used to perform unit tests for windows 8.x, developer license must be installed on the computer.

So, there is no way to run tests for Windows 8.1 on Hosted Agent. You need to [deploy a Windows build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows) or [set up an on-premises build controller + build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166931.aspx) to test Windows 8.1 application.

Comment: Is it possible to run tests for a Windows 10 app on a Hosted agent?

Comment: Developer Mode replaces the use of a developer license in the Windows 10 operating system. You just enable Developer Mode for a device once for these tasks from the settings for the device. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development